# sticky navigation and scroll to top functions work individually, but don't work together

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop

I have two scripts on my website only, single they work, together they don't... what am I missing here?

first script:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var sticky = navigation.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    navigation.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navigation.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

second script:

```
mybutton = document.getElementById("tothetop");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 98 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 98) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

I don't see why they don't work together.

Comment: What do you mean by two functions not working together? Is it your first function not calling the function or both not work.

Answer (score 1):

You override onscroll function by doing your double declaration

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()}; // oh no, I'll be replaced

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()}; // I'll be called only
```

try:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
  scrollFunction();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, worked! Oh i see now - i did not know that this "window.onscroll" can not be used 2 times :) Thank you!